# Show activity in Frame Layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-framelayout

I have one layout called sample.xml
`

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/actionbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

`

i have two class 
one is tab.java
second is wallpaper.java

so can any one suggest me how can i show wallpaper.java in frame-layout

Comment: Why are you using Frame layout?

Comment: What you want to achieve??

Comment: What do you mean by this "how can i show wallpaper.java in frame-layout"?

Comment: Make your walpaper.java a Fragment and load it inside your FrameLayout.

Comment: @Rani well my porpose is when some one click on action bar then i have to show different activity and in action bar i have three button

Comment: @bakriOnFire can i do this without Fragment ?

Comment: Same question @Raghunandan.. You are not clear with your requirement OP.

Comment: Ya you can do this with fragments

Comment: @user2783386 you have tabs in action bar. on each tab selection you need to show load a different fragment. Is that what you are looking for. From your comments that is as close as i can guess. If not pls post your code of action bar and the activity code

Comment: @Raghunandan yes you are right but thing is that i don't want to change  java file

Comment: @user2783386 why not? your requirement is very unclear pls post more info or code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Fragment` is the best option to achieve what you want.

But if you don't want to do it, you can make your `welcome.java` a normal file(not an activity) and return your layout as a view from that file.
Then you can directly add this returned view into your `FrameLayout`.

**EDIT**

1) Remove the `extends Activity` from your class.

2) Remove all `@Override` from that class.

3) Change your `onCreate` to this:-

```
Activity activity;
View v;
public View onCreate(Activity activity)//change the name if you want
 {
    this.activity = activity;
    Typeface rt=Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"font/Carleton.ttf");
    //super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    LayoutInflator li = activity.getLauoutInflator();
    v = li.inflate(R.layout.wallpaper, null);
    .
    .
    .
    return v;
}
```

4) Replace all `findViewById` with `v.findViewById`

5) Replace all `getResources()` with `activity.getResources()`

6) Then in your `tab.java` add the `onCreate` of `welcome.java` in your `FrameLayout` as

```
Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
frameLayout.addView(welcome.onCreate(this));
```

Comment: Thank you well can you provide me an example? how can i return view from oncreate() method ?

Comment: [usethis link for code](https://github.com/Gupta126/code/blob/master/wallpaper.java)

Comment: you'll have to change all the Activity related references to the variable activity..

Comment: well just try to change from your side

Comment: hey bro i getting error `wvNavInfo = (WebView) v1.findViewById(R.id.webView1);` shows me NullPointerException

Comment: please see this code i am getting error at `main_frame.addView(sld.onCreate(this));` error about change to click listener  please tell me what to do   `_slideshow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(View v) {
    try {
    main_frame.removeAllViews();
            main_frame.addView(sld.onCreate(this));
     
    } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
    }

   }
  });`

Comment: `main_frame.addView(sld.onCreate(this));` i am getting error at this line when i am using it in click event of button

Answer (score 2):

I am not getting what you want to achieve..
But If you want to use layout something like tabs, you can achieve it using [ViewPager](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-viewpager-example/) or [TabHost](http://android.codeandmagic.org/2011/07/android-tabs-with-fragments/)

**EDIT**

[This](http://droidista.blogspot.in/2012/08/making-actionbarsherlock-and.html) might help you to achieve your requirement.